# Google sheet + App Script + HTML Stop Element from clearing after onclick function in google sheet sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm using a sidebar on my google sheet to select starting date and ending date I have a button that onclick set those date on my google sheet and that is working fine what I'm having issue with is I would like for the selected date to remain and not be cleared after the button is clicked here's my gs code

```
    function StartDate(numstart){
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const ws = ss.getSheetByName('DateFromTo').getRange('A2'); 
      ws.setValue(numstart)
    }

  function EndDate(numend){
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName('DateFromTo').getRange('B2');
    ws.setValue(numend)
  }
```

and here's part of my html code I've tried adding "return false" but that didn't work

```
<h4 class="text-left">From Date</h4>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate" name ="startDate" required>
        <h4 class="text-left">To Date</h4>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate" name ="endDate" required>
        </div>


<div class="form-group"> 
        <button  onclick="StartDate();EndDate(); return false;" type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-2 btn-lg">Set Date</button>
    </div>



    <script>
        function StartDate(){
        var startdate = document.getElementById("startDate");
        var numstart = startdate.value
        google.script.run.StartDate(numstart);
        document.getElementById("startDate").value=("")
        
        }
    </script>


    <script>
        function EndDate(){
        var startdate = document.getElementById("endDate");
        var numend = startdate.value
        google.script.run.EndDate(numend);
        document.getElementById("endDate").value=("")
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `what I'm having issue with is I would like for the selected date to remain and not be cleared after the button is clicked`. I apologize for this. I thought that your `document.getElementById("startDate").value=("")` and `document.getElementById("endDate").value=("")` can be used for clearing it. So can I ask you about your situation? 1. What browser are you using? 2. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue including your current script?

Comment: Hi Tanaike thanks for your reply here's a link to my test sheet I created to test my issue https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/159ke32xRbtJ-z_T4Z7_5Of8kuZ1MvdFX6dtBAYRD4ao/edit?usp=sharing 
thanks again

Comment: Chrome browser is what I'm using

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- At first, I had thought that you want to clear the input tag when the button is clicked. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I saw `I need those 2 field above to retain there selected values after clicking the post button` and `what im trying to get is once I selected the From Date and the To Date from this sidebar date picker then click on Post Date button I want the selected date to remain or be reposted in the From Date and To date feild of this Google sidebar instead of being cleared`. In this case, I understood that when you selected the dates for `From Date` and `To Date` and click the button `Post Date`, you want to keep the selected dates. And, when you click the button `Clear/Cancel`, you want to clear the dates.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `StartDate()` and `EndDate()` in Javascript side as follows.

```
function StartDate(){
  var startdate = document.getElementById("startDate");
  var numstart = startdate.value
  google.script.run.StartDate(numstart);
}

function EndDate(){
  var startdate = document.getElementById("endDate");
  var numend = startdate.value
  google.script.run.EndDate(numend);
}
```

And, for `<button  onclick="Clear()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning col-md-2 btn-lg">Clear / Cancel</button>` which is not shown in your question, please prepare the function `Clear()` in Javascript side as follows.

```
function Clear() {
  document.getElementById("startDate").value = "";
  document.getElementById("endDate").value = "";
}
```

- By above modification, when you selected the dates for `From Date` and `To Date` and click the button `Post Date`, the selected dates are kept. And, when you click the button `Clear/Cancel`, the selected dates are cleared.

Comment: Thanks again Tanaike this works exactly as I needed it

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.